# Resize image very slow when it process

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to resize an image and when run my code but resize process is very slow.
My code as below :

```
void _selectImage() async {
try {
  final checkDataImage =
      await _imagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

  if (checkDataImage != null) {
    print(checkDataImage.name);
    print(checkDataImage.path);
    setState(() {
      pickedImage = checkDataImage;
    });
  }
} catch (err) {
  print(err);
  pickedImage = null;
}

final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
final path = tempDir.path;

Img.Image image = Img.decodeImage(await pickedImage.readAsBytes());
Img.Image smallerImg = Img.copyResize(image, width: 500);

int rand = new Math.Random().nextInt(999999999);

var compressImg = new File('$path/image_$rand.jpg')
  ..writeAsBytesSync(Img.encodeJpg(smallerImg, quality: 90));     

setState(() {
  if (!mounted) return;
  _imageUpload = compressImg;
});}
```

What wrong my code, please help to faster it process ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Judging from your code, I'm assuming that you are using the [image package](https://pub.dev/packages/image) for these calls. That package is written entirely in Dart with no dependency on `dart:io`, so it doesn't benefit from the speed of native code or hardware acceleration. As such, image decoding, encoding, and resizing are likely going to be very slow, which is why the package owner recommends doing those processes in a separate isolate (thread).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, `package:image` is written in pure Dart and will never be as fast as native solutions that can be multithreaded and hardware accelerated.

While using another isolate will stop the image tasks blocking the UI, if you need to do this as fast as possible, I suggest you use something like the [ImageMagick library](https://imagemagick.org), or if you only need Android and iOS support, [`package:flutter_image_compress`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress).